# Android open browser using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have this Alarm that is triggered with AlarmManager from time to time.
I wanted it to open the browser when the Alarm is triggered.

I added the code I was trying to the onReceive(), but it doensn't seem to work this way. Do you have any idea?

Code of the question between //// from HERE, until //// to Here

```
package com.tribta.test;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    // Alarm triggered
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(300); // Vibrate for 300 milliseconds

        //// from HERE

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        browserIntent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);

        //// to HERE

        wl.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

        int delay = 5000;

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + delay, pi);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it doensn't seem to work" means. You should be getting an error message in LogCat, indicating that you do not have `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on your `Intent`.

Comment: Have you tried wether the Broadcast is received at all? maybe you did a mistake on the registration of the receiver

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean that the browser is not opening. It's a bit odd but when I comment that part both the vibrater and Toast notification show up, but when I put that code it only vibrates

Comment: @BAAAZINGA yes, because if I comment that piece of code the rest works fine, the toas notification and vibration

Comment: I repeat: You should be getting an error message in LogCat, indicating that you do not have `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on your `Intent`.  Android specifically blocks background components (e.g., `BroadcastReceiver`) from starting activities without this flag. In part, that is because starting an activity from the background is a user-hostile act, as you do not know what the user is doing in the foreground at the time.

Comment: It worked! @CommonsWare, I only added browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start an activity from the background (e.g., from a `BroadcastReceiver` or a `Service`) unless you add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent`.